# Replace content in file using bash

Tags: bash, centos7, editing

I am looking to replace the line export KEY_COUNTRY="US" with the data read in the variable $COUNTRY in the file /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/vars

In my previous builds which I used with CentOS6, i used the command replace which is bundled with mysql-server. But now that function is no longer available, i am looking for ideas on alternate command to replace the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us some more context? It looks like a job for `sed`, but it's not entirely clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am writing a automation script for openVPN installation. We are using easy-rsa to build CA CERT keys. To do this, I want to edit the configurations in the file vars and replace the data which user enters. Example export KEY_EMAIL="me@myhost.mydomain" must be replaced by export KEY_EMAIL=$email where $email would be read from the user input.

Comment: In any case, when doing template substitution with USER-PROVIDED DATA you must be super, super careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`, but keep in mind that it can fail if $COUNTRY contrains control characters.

```
sed -i 's/KEY_COUNTRY="US"/KEY_COUNTRY="'"$COUNTRY"'"/' file
```

Using Perl would be safer, as it doesn't interpret variable contents as part of the syntax:

```
perl -i -pe 's/KEY_COUNTRY="US"/KEY_COUNTRY="$ENV{COUNTRY}"/' -- file
```

$COUNTRY must be accessible in the perl process, i.e. you need to `export` it or assign to it

```
COUNTRY=$COUNTRY perl ...
```

Comment: @123: I don't like to backslash doublequotes.

Comment: @choroba fair enough